# py.image.save_as() function crush the code

Tags: python, plotly

I use plotly on python to generate charts and suddenly I started to get errors during running. It seems like the error occur while saving the chart as image.
The call that get me this error is:

```
py.image.save_as(fig, pic_name)
```

that is the function that makes the call:

```
def bar_chart_general(tags, malicious, benign, pic_name, xTitle, yTitle, Title):
    data1 = go.Bar(x=tags, y=benign, name='Benign')
    data2 = go.Bar(x=tags, y=malicious, name='Malicious')
    data = [data1, data2]
    annotations = [dict(x=xi, y=yi,text=str(yi), xanchor='right', yanchor='bottom', showarrow=False,) for xi, yi in zip(tags, benign)] +\
              [dict(x=xi, y=yi,text=str(yi), xanchor='left', yanchor='bottom', showarrow=False,) for xi, yi in zip(tags, malicious)]
    layout = go.Layout(xaxis=go.XAxis(title=xTitle), yaxis=go.YAxis(title=yTitle), annotations=annotations)
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    py.image.save_as(fig, pic_name)
    return
```

and here I call the function:

```
# downloads per source
df = pd.read_csv("input_csv/downloads_per_source.csv")
bar_chart_general(df["source"], df["malicious"], df["benign"], "output_charts/downloads_per_source.png", 'Source', 'Downloads',
              'Downloads per Source')
```

that is the error I get:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/zionina/PycharmProjects/Charts/ChartsCreator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/zionina/PycharmProjects/Charts/ChartsCreator.py", line 130, in <module>
'Downloads per Source')
  File "C:/Users/zionina/PycharmProjects/Charts/ChartsCreator.py", line 81, in bar_chart_general
    py.image.save_as(fig, pic_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py", line 831, in save_as
    img = cls.get(figure_or_data, format, width, height, scale)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py", line 744, in get
    response = v2.images.create(payload)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\plotly\api\v2\images.py", line 18, in create
    return request('post', url, json=body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\plotly\api\v2\utils.py", line 153, in request
    validate_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\plotly\api\v2\utils.py", line 79, in validate_response
    raise exceptions.PlotlyRequestError(message, status_code, content)
plotly.exceptions.PlotlyRequestError: Request was throttled. Expected available in 66964.0 seconds.
```

thanks for anyone who can help

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the AIP key. I changed the key and it works again